# Crop image with smooth edges in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, image-processing

I want to crop image with smooth edges like alpha gradient.

This is not related to UI, I want it internally on actual image.

[image]

I can crop an image like this.

```
private var mInputImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "example")!
let croppingRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

let cgImage = mInputImage.cgImage! 
let croppedCGImage = cgImage.cropping(to: croppingRect)
```

But how can I make the border smooth?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask]. Show us your "example" image in its original state, and how you want it to look with "smooth edges."

Comment: OK - first, the "example" image you added is not cropped to `0,0 200,200` ... so it's not clear if you also want to be scaling the image. There are various ways to get the result you want - but, do you want to generate a `UIImage` like that? Or, do you just want to display it on the screen like that? Search for `swift UIImage feather edges` and take a look at some of the results. Try the different approaches and see if you find one that fits your actual goal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.